# Having action in a Ember view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I am using ember view for my inputs

So my code looks like this

`{{input type="text" value=search_text class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."}}`

Now I need to look at `keypress` events and fire a function like so

`{{action 'handle_search' on='keyPress'}}`

The only issue is that obviously I cannot nest handlebar helpers inside of each other like this.

So what would be a work around for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this statement:  The only issue is that obviously I cannot nest handlebar helpers inside of each other like this.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @kingpin2k I cannot do this `{{input {{action 'handle_search' on='keyPress'}} type="text" value=search_text class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."}}`

Answer (score 0):

http://emberjs.com/guides/views/built-in-views/  Here is a link to extending the default ember views.  Essentially what you need to do is extend the built in ember control, and give it a `kepress:` function that will be called when the event is fired.

You can see one of the examples does this but with the `change:` event.

UPDATE::

Here is a jsbin to illustrate http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rukuremu/1/edit?html,css,js,output